# CheckBox in Listview in xamerin.form

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

Please help me out, how I can implement `CheckBox` in `ListView` with sample code if you can provide to me and a button which help me out which `ListView` is been checked (using xamarin.forms)

Answer (score -1):

Don't sure, what **exactly** you are searching...
But, you can find an example for a Multiselect-Listbox here:
[Example Multiselect-ListView](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17885/multiselect-listviews)

I use it for multiselection and - with some small changes in the logic - also as "Radio-Button" (one selection out of n).

Comment: Do you have a solution for a single Checkbox?

Comment: With small changes of the logic, you also can use my example with only one Checkbox or use it as radiobutton (only on item out of more).